# How do i view eps file in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, eps

I am new to iPhone app development.
Can someone help me in displaying eps file content in iphone.

Thanks
Rajeev

Answer (score 1):

The Mac OS X CoreGraphics framework includes CGPSConverter (which can be used to do this), but this functionality is not available in the iOS CoreGraphics framework.  Your only option is to use a 3rd party library or perhaps a web service.